# Excel reference in C# SIlverlight app not accepted

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, export-to-excel

I have a C# Silverlight app that lets the user select which spreadsheet they want to have updated from a flat file.
I have had to use the ExcelLite tool - http://excellite.codeplex.com/
I download and then i copies to the project folder then i have add reference and code here:

using Lite.ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet; but can't get a build there is this error: I have changed the properties as below:

Error   9   Could not load the assembly file:///C:\MyFolder\14-03-2012\Binaries\Binaries\Lite.ExcelLibrary.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information.

Aliases     Global
Copy Local  True
Culture        ** unable to change is blank
Description     ** unable to change is blank
Embedded Interop types     False
Datalib
File Type      **unable to change   ("Assembly")
Identity       **Unable to change   ("Lite.Excel.Library")
Path        C:/ etc
Resolved    **unable to change ("True")
Runtime version ...
Specific version  True

Strong name   **unable to change ("False")
version   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file, hit Properties, then "Security" (or "Advanced", I can't remember) and click the "Unblock" button.

**Edit**

Apparently it's right there on the general tab, see my comment below.

Comment: IN SOlution explorer it only gives properties not advanced. I can't locate this unblock part. I added it as a reference.

Comment: On file propery  I don't see the UNBLOCK option.

Comment: It's the windows file properties, not Visual Studio. Here's an example: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124367-open-file-security-warning-unblock-file.html